# Google map display kml(inside is a image url) not correct when zoom level is 1

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I want to display a kml (inside is a image url and bounds),by right it should show multiple images when google map zoom is 1,but it show only 1,how to do to show other part of the google map?

kml code:

[kml code as attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d03K.png)

js code:

```
ctaLayerIR = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url:'http://xxxxxx/I201603070300.XAEWJ.global.full.3600x1200.kml',
        preserveViewport: true,
        clickable: false,
        zIndex: 9999,
        suppressInfoWindows:false       
    });
    ctaLayerIR.setMap(map);
```

current display:
[how to display the right side kml to left side too?their bounds is same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrSRq.png)

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that you have exceeded the size limit for KML resources since you used a large image file. You can checkout this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#restrictions) for the exact numbers.